# DNS Scavenging not deleting stale DNS record

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-dns

I have set the following DNS Setting for Scavenging so that stale record must be automatically deleted, still it is not working ( Please see the print-screen )[image]

[image]

[image]

24 hrs has been passed still Stale record is there, Please see the below print-screen - "Delete this record when it become stale is set to 8/31/2012" still it is showing in my Dns management window

Comment: If you right click on the DNS server and choose "scavenge stale resource records" does it work manually?  Also, see here to run a script to list out the stale records to verify http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2008/10/10/microsoft-dns-stale-records/

Comment: Was this particular record dynamically registered or was it created manually? If it was created manually it won't be scavenged. Static records don't get scavenged.

Comment: If i choose "scavenge stale resource records" manually, it does not work. I don't know why?

Comment: Yes, it was registered dynamically

Comment: Is scavenging enabled on the zone? (I don't see a screenshot above...)

Comment: If so, when was scavenging enabled on the zone? You will have to wait until at least the length of the refresh interval has passed before any action will be taken. Check for events 2501/2502 on the scavenging server.